# Solving non-linear equations in R

Tags: r, solver

I have a **single variable exponential equation** that I need to solve in **R**. All the solver functions and packages I have investigated so far (eg nleqslv, pracma, etc.)  need a vector input as the initial guess for the value of the variable. However, hte variable can take an arbitrary value (so it's difficult to provide an initial guess) and in some cases, my choice of initial value significantly affects the final outcome.

**Do you know if there are any solver functions available in R that doesn't need an initial guess? (ie similar to solve function in matlab)**

Edit: Here is the equation I'm trying to solve (all the variables other than t are known):

```
T_eqn<-((y-y_star)/(x-x_star)) -((1/137.88)*(exp(lambda_prime*t_zero)-exp(lambda_prime*t))/(exp(lambda*t_zero)-exp(lambda*t))) -(1/137.88)*(mu_star/(x-x_star))*(exp(lambda*t)-1)*(((exp(lambda_prime*t_zero)-exp(lambda_prime*t))/(exp(lambda*t_zero)-exp(t*lambda)))-((exp(t*lambda_prime)-1)/(exp(lambda*t)-1)))==0
```

And here are the values for each of the known variables (y and x change in each iteration of the code):

```
y_star <- 15.63
x_star <- 18.750
z_star <- 38.83
lambda <- 0.155125 * 10^(-9)
lambda_prime <- 0.98485* 10^(-9)
lambda_zegond <- 0.049475 * 10^(-9)
mu_star <- 9.66
kappa_star <- 3.90
t_zero <- 3.8 * 10^9
```

Comment: Sounds interesting, it might help others understand the problem better if you say what the function is exactly.

Comment: @RobertDodier Here is the equation I want to solve (other than t, everything else is known): 
  `T_eqn<-((y-y_star)/(x-x_star)) -((1/137.88)*(exp(lambda_prime*t_zero)-exp(lambda_prime*t))/(exp(lambda*t_zero)-exp(lambda*t))) -(1/137.88)*(mu_star/(x-x_star))*(exp(lambda*t)-1)*(((exp(lambda_prime*t_zero)-exp(lambda_prime*t))/(exp(lambda*t_zero)-exp(t*lambda)))-((exp(t*lambda_prime)-1)/(exp(lambda*t)-1)))`

Comment: @Dan99, please edit your question to include this information, and include definitions for all of the auxiliary variables (`y`, `y_star`, `x`, `x_star`, `lambda`, `lambda_prime`, `t_zero`, `mu_star`, etc.).  Matlab's `solve` function is a **symbolic** solver (you can access Python's `sympy` via R, or other computer algebra systems such as yacas)

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks! I tried sympy but it couldn't find a solution. I have also edited the question

Comment: You won't find any such function, because this is a **non-convex** function, which means solvers will only get you what's called a *local optimum*, and that optimum depends on your initial guess. If a given software does not require you to provide an initial guess, chances are it's either starting with all-zeros or with random numbers.

Comment: Hmm, this is an interesting problem. You might want to take it to math.stackexchange.com. I looked at the equation for x = 20 and y = 12 (with the stated values for the other variables) and the resulting expression has a limit of -1.818 as t goes to minus infinity, and it appears to become very large and negative as t increases. So on the face of it, I don't see any solutions. Maybe solutions exist for some values of x and y; what are typical values for x and y?

Comment: @anymous.asker good to know. The only issue with R vs matlab solver is that the initial choice of t in R seems to hugely affect the answers in some of the cases.

Comment: @RobertDodier that's right! x and y values always fall in a limited range. x is usually somewhere in the 17-19 range (eg 18.7) and y usually between 15-16 (eg 15.6).

Comment: Dan, I don't think the comment from @anymous.asker is relevant here, since your problem is solving an equation, and anymous.asker is describing a problem with optimization (i.e., finding minimum or maximum).

Comment: Dan, with the stated values for x and y, I get a solution near t = -0.02. Plotting the function seems to show it is monotonic (either increasing or decreasing, for different values of x and y) -- maybe you can prove that. It may be possible to get a symbolic solution in terms of Lambert functions (a web search will find some info) but I didn't try that. I know you are looking for a symbolic solution, but if you can't find one you might try to just scope out the range of x and y that are relevant and verify that you can find numerical solutions in that range.